# MySQL Trigger that executes a Python script

Tags: python, mysql, windows, triggers, automation

I have a Python script that:
1. reads the MySQL  `input_table` of latitudes and longitudes, 
2. computes weather_data  using OpenWeatherMap API.
3.  INSERTS this weather_data into a  `weather_table`

This Python script  does what is needed everytime I manually run it on my Windows Command Prompt. The query is: how do I ensure that this .py script runs everytime a new record is INSERTed into my `input_table` (without me having to manually run the .py script)?

To this effect, I wrote a MySQL trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER ds_testdb1.weather_trigger_1 AFTER INSERT ON ds_testdb1.input_table 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
DECLARE cmd TEXT;
DECLARE result int;
SET cmd= 'python C:/Users/SS19/Desktop/insert_weather.py';
SET result= sys_exec(cmd);       -- is a UDF (User Defined Function)
END $$
DELIMITER ;

-- Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)
```

To test the trigger, my workflow is:
a) INSERT 1 record into the `input_table` 
b) check the corresponding result in the `weather_table`

Now, when I  Insert 1 record into the `input_table` , the message on MySQL Workbench is '1 row(s) affected'. However, no change is seen the the `weather_table`. Is it because I declared the datatype of `result` to be `int' but the`result` returns a record that looks like:

---

[image: datatypes of columns in the weather_table]

The Overarching question is: how do I ensure that this .py script runs to completion (successfully performs INSERTS into the `weather-table`) everytime a new record is INSERTed into my input_table (without me having to manually run the .py script)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

`"SET cmd= 'python C:/Users/SS19/Desktop/insert_weather.py';"`

with the following

`"SET cmd= 'C:/ ..full path to python.exe ../python C:/Users/SS19/Desktop/insert_weather.py';".`

It worked for me.